# How to get number from a string with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

i want to get the number from a string

Example:

```
a = '22,123 games'
```

Result:

```
result = 22123
```

Comment: where is your code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to find where the number is.
I assume that it's before the first space, so

```
number = a[0 : a.find(' ')]
```

Then you have to remove commas:

```
noCommas = number.replace(',', '')
```

And then convert to int:

```
res = int(noCommas)
```